# How to connect Time Series Insight to Azure IoT Hub over Private Connection

Tags: azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge, azure-timeseries-insights

I've got an Azure IoT Hub (Public Access Restricted) and having a Time Series Insight.
And I want to connect this time series insight to IoT Hub over the private connection so I don't need to make IoT Hub publicly accessible.

Creating a private endpoint in Time series insight didn't work for me.

Comment: Are you following the article here? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/time-series-insights/how-to-private-links

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got the answer, So the issue was while keeping your IoT Hub Private or on the **Selected IP Ranges**, There is a checkbox in the end that says **Do you also want the IP Restriction applied on Build-in Endpoints**. Uncheck it and problem solved.

So in the end, To maintain the connectivity to the TSI environment with IoT Hub on the private endpoint, The IoT Hub can remain on the private network but built-in endpoints should be public.

That's my understanding.

Answer (score 2):

Time Series Insights just released private endpoint capability in public preview.  See this link: [Private network access with Azure Private Link (preview)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/time-series-insights/concepts-private-links).  You should be able to connect your Azure IoT Hub to this private endpoint capability.